# Creating state in a Flask webapplication

Tags: python, flask, state

I'm building a webapplication with the Flask framework of python. On the server I would like to preserve some state. I think the following code example makes my goal clear (and was also my initial idea):

```
name = ""

@app.route('/<input_name>')
def home(input_name):
    global name
    name = input_name
    return "name set"

@app.route('/getname')
def getname():
    global name
    return name
```

Though when I deployed my website the response for an */getname* request behaves inconsistent because there are multiple thread-instances of the code (I could be wrong). I have some plausible solutions to overcome this problem but I wonder if there would be a more 'clean' solution:

Solution 1: read and write the name from a database (a database seems like overkill if a only want to store 1 variable)

Solution 2: store the value of *name* in a file and setup a locking mechanism so that only one process/thread could write to the file at the same moment.

Goal: when client 'A' requests *www.website.com/sven* and after that client 'B' requests *www.website.com/getname* I want the response for client B to be 'sven'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Flask already have [session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.session) that answers to your question.

Comment: @ChihebNexus Thank for your reply, but with the use of session the variable is client-specific. I added an example to my question to explain the wanted behavior

Comment: Yes, the variable will be related to the user session. If you want to make it persistant, you have to store it ... And your DB comes in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example should not be done with global state, it will not work for the reason you mentioned - requests might land into different processes that will have different global values.

You can handle storing global variables by using a key-value cache, such as memcached or Redis, or file-system based cache - check Flask-Chaching package and particular docs https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#built-in-cache-backends